# Django custom template tag passing variable number of arguments

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to write a django custom template tag which will be called in the template as follow:

**Template:**

```
{% load tag_name %}
{% tag_fn arg1 arg2 ... arg n %}
```

`arg1, ..., arg n` are python variables.

**Template tag:**

In template tag i have four dicitonaries

`d1 = {"key1": "some text" + str(arg2), "key2":" some text" + str(arg m)` like wise i have four dictionaries.

based on the value of `arg1` the corresponding dictionary should be rendered and i want the template tag to return `"some text value(arg1) some text value(arg m)"` to the template as a result.

Please suggest a way to implement it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ The Django documentation is actually rather comprehensive on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any number of variables to your custom template tag by using Python's built in way of passing in multiple values from a list. Example:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.tag('my_tag')
def do_whatever(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    """
    Pass all of the arguments defined in the template tag except the first one,
    which will be the name of the template tag itself.
    Example: {% do_whatever arg1 arg2 arg3 %}
    *bits[1:] would be: [arg1, arg2, arg3]
    """
    return MyTemplateNode(*bits[1:])

class MyTemplateNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()

    def render(self, context):
        do_something_else()
```

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to just use Python's normal way of accepting a variable number of args:

```py
@register.simple_tag()
def my_tag(*args):
  # do stuff with args, which is a list of all the arguments
  return 'what you want to output'
```

Then you can use it like you wanted:

```
{% my_tag arg1 arg2 arg3 %}
```